# Why is my JAVA_HOME environment variable an empty string?

Tags: java, r

When I run `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` an empty string is returned, yet somehow when I run `library(rJava)` the package loads with no problems. Why does my JAVA_HOME environment variable not need to be set to the jre file?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is nothing special. It's just an environment variable that applications are aware of and can check when Java isn't on the system path. If Java's already on the path, or the application has an alternative way to know locate Java (e.g. via configuration) then JAVA_HOME is irrelevant.

Comment: Java itself does not use JAVA_HOME; some third party tools and libraries depend on that environment variable being set to work properly. If you aren't using those, then nothing uses it. Also, if you never set it why are you surprised it is not set?

Comment: R u on Windows? if yes, you might want to go through the code in https://github.com/cran/rJava/blob/master/R/windows/FirstLib.R